# How to do proper cancellation within a blazor server app?

Tags: c#, blazor-server-side, cancellation, cancellationtokensource

I have a method bound to a click event from a table row. The method which gets called is:

```
private async Task BestelldispositionsItemClicked(Bestelldisposition pos)
{
    _tokenSourceClicked.Cancel();
    _tokenSourceClicked = new CancellationTokenSource();
    _belege.Clear();
    using FbController2 fbController = new FbController2();
    _isLoading = true;
    _selectedBestelldisposition = pos;

    await foreach (var beleg in pos.GetBelegeMitPositionAsync(fbController, _tokenSourceClicked.Token))
    {
        if (_tokenSourceClicked.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            break;
        }

        _belege.Add(beleg);
        StateHasChanged();
    }


    _isLoading = false;
}
```

As you can see I am canceling the previous task with `_tokenSourceClicked.Cancel();`. `_belege` is a `List<Beleg>` which gets cleared afterwards. The token is being passed down to antoher function `GetBelegeMitPositionAsync` which is defined as:

```
public async IAsyncEnumerable<Auftrag> GetBelegeMitPositionAsync(FbController2 fbController, [EnumeratorCancellation] CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    if (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        fbController.AddParameter("@BPOS_A_ARTIKELNR", Artikelnummer);
        var data = await fbController.SelectDataAsync(@"SELECT BELE_N_NR FROM BELEGPOS BP 
INNER JOIN BELEGE B ON (B.BELE_N_NR = BP.BPOS_N_NR AND B.BELE_A_TYP = 'AU')
WHERE BPOS_A_TYP = 'AU' AND BPOS_A_ARTIKELNR = @BPOS_A_ARTIKELNR
AND BELE_L_ERLEDIGT = 'N'");


        foreach (DataRow row in data.Rows)
        {
            if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                break;
            }
            int belegnummer = row.Field<int>("BELE_N_NR");

            if (belegnummer > 0)
            {
                var auftrag = await Auftrag.GetAuftragAsync(belegnummer, fbController);

                if (auftrag is not null)
                {
                    if (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                    {
                        yield return auftrag;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see I don't add/return anything when a canellation has being requested. However when I click my table row in quick succession, I'll see the same items up to 3 times within my list. How is this even possible if I cancel all old running methods before I call my method again? Does anyone know what I should do different here?

Comment: just guessing here, but could there be an UI Issue when the for loop is breaked via Cancel the StateHasChanged(); might not be called?

Comment: @jeb no. This has nothing todo with it. StateHasChanged gets called automatically at the end of the method by the framework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How is this even possible if I cancel all old running methods before I call my method again? Does anyone know what I should do different here?

`GetBelegeMitPositionAsync` is checking the cancellation token for the CTS that was canceled; but the `await foreach` loop in `BestelldispositionsItemClicked` is checking the CTS member variable directly, which is changed after the old one is cancelled.

I strongly recommend following the standard cancellation pattern for .NET. This pattern means that cancelled code should not return; it should throw `OperationCanceledException`. This is most easily done by replacing all `IsCancellationRequested` checks with calls to `ThrowIfCancellationRequested`. Also, all cancelable code should use (a copy of) the `CancellationToken` rather than checking the `CancellationTokenSource` directly.

E.g.:

```
private async Task BestelldispositionsItemClicked(Bestelldisposition pos)
{
  _tokenSourceClicked.Cancel();
  _tokenSourceClicked = new CancellationTokenSource();
  var token = _tokenSourceClicked.Token;
  _belege.Clear();
  using FbController2 fbController = new FbController2();
  _isLoading = true;
  _selectedBestelldisposition = pos;

  try
  {
    await foreach (var beleg in pos.GetBelegeMitPositionAsync(fbController, token))
    {
      _belege.Add(beleg);
      StateHasChanged();
    }
  }
  catch (OperationCanceledException) { }
  finally
  {
    _isLoading = false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this example. One last question regarding the copy of the token. How would I cancel this operation now from IAsyncDisposable ? I declared my CancellationTokenSource at class level to have access to it within DisposeAsync but don't I need to call Cancel(); from the copied token?

Comment: @MarvinKlein: If this type implements `IAsyncDisposable`, you can still call `Cancel` from `DisposeAsync`. You just don't want the *consuming* code accessing the `CancellationTokenSource`.